# Use JSON data coming from WebApi in AngularJS application

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I get some data from a WebApi, the answer (below the code to get the datas) is in JSON. But I can't access this result from angularJS. The datas look like :

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "result": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "name": "Français",
      "code": "FR",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "$id": "3",
      "name": "Néerlandais",
      "code": "NL",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "$id": "4",
      "name": "English",
      "code": "EN",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

But I get the error below when I try to display the result :

```
data.result is undefined
```

I get the data like this :

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp')
        .factory('dataService', ['$q', '$http', dataService]);

    function dataService($q, $http) {
        return {
            initFormCustomer: initFormCustomer
        };

        function initFormCustomer() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:123456/api/forminit/customer/',
                headers: {
                },
                transformResponse: transformCustomer,
                cache: true
            })
            .then(sendResponseData)
            .catch(sendGetCustomerError)
        }

        function sendResponseData(response) {
            return response.data;
        }

        function transformCustomer(data, headersGetter) {
            var transformed = angular.fromJson(data.result);
            console.log(data.result[0]);
            return transformed;
        }

        function sendGetCustomerError(response) {
            return $q.reject('Error retrieving customer(s). (HTTP status: ' + response.status + ')');
        }
    }
}());
```

The controller :

```
(function () {

    angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('customerController', ['$location', '$scope', 'dataService', CustomerController]);

    function CustomerController($location, $scope, dataService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.languages = dataService.initFormCustomer();
    }

}());
```

Comment: console.log(data). somewhere between receiving the "answer" and the done callback you're unwrapping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the transform function gets a json string that you have to deserialize before using it as an object... try sth like:

```
function transformCustomer(data, headersGetter) {
        var transformed = angular.fromJson(data);
        console.log(transformed.result[0]);
        return transformed.result;
    }
```

Additionally you may look at the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http . There is some code showing how to append a transform to the default one (that do the deserialization and XSRF checks)

Comment: In the controller when I do this "var languages = dataService.initFormCustomer();  alert(languages[0]);" I get an undifined and in the console "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress". When I try this "alert(languages.result[0]);" I get "result is undifined". But in the transformCustomer that's look ok

Comment: You are returning a promise in initFormCustomer - so you can't use it directly.